# Identification: Replacement (optical?) cable for Huawei hg8247u router

Tags: router, cable, optical-cable

I have a friend in a holiday villa in spain with a Huawei hg8247u router.  He says he needs to replace a broken cable, but I don't recognise it ( it looks like some type of optical cable)[image: Optical cable pic 2]

[image: Optical cable pic 2]

[image: back of router where in clicks in]

The manual only calls it a Optical port [Manual](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000176963)

I can find optical cables online, but not one that matches this.  Do you know the name of this cable and can you get a replacement for it?

Note the cable is the same on both ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a SC/APC simplex/single mode fiber cable.

This is as per the [port spec](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100024767) on the support page for the product.

Comment: No sweat. There is also SC/UPC which has a slightly different connection. Check if you need APC or UPC. It's hard to tell from the pictures if it's a flat or angled end.

Comment: it looks like this [link](https://www.fs.com/uk/products/42674.html),  I'll send him that link and get him to confirm that its the correct one

Comment: Which is why they're color-coded -- green generally means SC/APC, and blue indicates SC/UPC. (It is also visibly angled in the 1st photo, anyway.)

Comment: Useful to know @grawity